# how can I get rid of the original letters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function which takes a ROT13 encoded string as input and returns a decoded string. All letters will be uppercase. I should not transform any non-alphabetic character (i.e. spaces, punctuation), but do pass them on.
I returned a decoded string successfully but each letters is located in between the original letters.
Could you tell me where I make mistakes? Thank you.

```
function rot13(str) {
  const splitted = str.split(``)
  const regex = /\W+/
  let result = []
  for(let i=0;i<splitted.length;i++){
    if(!regex.test(splitted[i])){
      if(splitted[i].charCodeAt()>=65&&splitted[i].charCodeAt()<=77){
        result.push(String.fromCharCode(splitted[i].charCodeAt()+13))
       }
      if(splitted[i].charCodeAt()>=78&&splitted[i].charCodeAt()<=90){
        result.push(String.fromCharCode(splitted[i].charCodeAt()-13))} 
        }
   result.push(splitted[i])
   }
  return result.join(``)
 }

//it has to be FREE CODE CAMP
console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"))//FSREERER CPOBDQER CPANMZPC
//it has to be FREE PIZZA!
console.log(rot13("SERR CVMMN!")) //FSREERER PCIVZMZMAN!
```

I tried to get rid of original letters to use slice() and replace() in each if block but it doesn’t work.

Comment: There two paths through the code that get to result.push.  One (deep inside the conditionals) pushes the char +/- 13, the other pushes the original.

Comment: Your conditions are not all correct. So when you have an alphanumerical character, you add to your result both the rotated character and the original one. Try looking at how `else if` and `else` work. A good starting point is [the `if..else` page of the MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: I solved. I didn't need to create a new array and should've written else if.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below function

```js
function rot13(str) {
  let decodedStr = "";
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
    
    if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) {
      // Decode uppercase letters
      decodedStr += String.fromCharCode(((charCode - 65 + 13) % 26) + 65);
    } else if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) {
      // Decode lowercase letters
      decodedStr += String.fromCharCode(((charCode - 97 + 13) % 26) + 97);
    } else {
      // Keep non-alphabetic characters as they are
      decodedStr += str.charAt(i);
    }
  }

  return decodedStr;
}

console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));  // Output: "FREE CODE CAMP"
console.log(rot13("SERR CVMMN!"));    // Output: "FREE PIZZA!"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That helps me a lot! It's more clear than mine